# PHP array_diff error

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare two different arrays. I am looking for the values that appear in array1 but do not appear in array2.  I have been banging my head against the wall about this because it seems so simple but does not work.

I have tried to find the keys of the array and then i was going to search for them

```
$orgKey;
      foreach($org as $k => $v){
          $orgKey[$k][] = $v['title'];
      }
      $newKey;
      foreach($new as $k => $v){
          $newKey[$k][] = $v['title'];

      }
      echo "orgkey";
      echo print_r($orgKey);
      echo "newkey<br/>";
      echo print_r($newKey);   
      $e = array_diff($orgKey,$newKey);
      echo print_r($e);
```

but this gives me an empty array everytime.

I have also tried foreach within foreach and realized i cannot find out how to search through a value that is not there without it duplicating because of the foreach loop itself.

```
foreach($org as $k => $v){
          foreach($new as $a => $b){  
              $count = count($new);
              $i = 0;
              if($v['title'] == $b['title']){
       //This is where i realize i will find duplicates of values that don't exist

              }

          }
      }
```

My arrays. $org

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Ahiris Angels
            [r_id] => 1276
            [t_id] => 1277
            [name] => 
            [column1] => 
            [column2] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Alistars Stars
            [r_id] => 1276
            [t_id] => 1278
            [name] => 
            [column1] => 
            [column2] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Ammumu
            [r_id] => 1276
            [t_id] => 1279
            [name] => 
            [column1] => 
            [column2] => 
        )
```

The $new array can be any values but keeps the structure of the $org array.

My Goal is to have an array like this $org

```
 [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => Ahiris Angels
                [r_id] => 1276
                [t_id] => 1277
                [name] => 
                [column1] => 
                [column2] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => Alistars Stars
                [r_id] => 1276
                [t_id] => 1278
                [name] => 
                [column1] => 
                [column2] => 
            )
```

Compare it to $new

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Ahiris Angels
                    [r_id] => 1276
                    [t_id] => 1277
                    [name] => 
                    [column1] => 
                    [column2] => 
                )
```

And my Result will be

```
[1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Alistars Stars
                    [r_id] => 1276
                    [t_id] => 1278
                    [name] => 
                    [column1] => 
                    [column2] => 
                )
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare two arrays like the one above or are you trying to compare 2 different elements of the array above (ex. $org[0] and $org[1])?

Comment: Didn't read, but "does not work" is worst title ever.

Comment: @Griwes. I edited the title. Thanks for your in depth solution to the problem.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but are $old and $new 2D arrays? that is, shouldn't you be checking $new[0] against $old[0]?

Comment: As the above says, terrible question title - it does work, tens of thousands of people use it daily.  You mean it is not doing what *you* believe it should, that is to say, you are not using it correctly.

Comment: here is a fast implementation of array_diff http://shiplu.mokadd.im/36/fastes-way-to-find-difference-of-very-large-php-arrays/

Comment: I titled my question wrong. If the answer doesn't help why would i accepted the answer? The title wasn't ridiculous or absurd intentionally. I thank those that offered help. I don't thank you or Griwes for the award of worst title ever. I made an amendment to the title yet u posted anyways. I will try and figure this out on my own. Thank you, for wasting my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're trying to do:

```
foreach ($org as $v)
{
    $orgKey[$v['title']] = $v;
}
foreach ($new as $v)
{
    $newKey[$v['title']] = $v;
}
$e = array_diff_key($orgKey, $newKey);
$e = array_values($e);
```

The last call to `array_values` is optional; it just reassigns sequential integers to the keys rather than leaving in the titles.